# when i am going to update the db i am getting error like this:

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am getting this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 0  
UPDATE `announcement_detail` SET `announcement_title` = 'test', `announcement_desc` = 'test announcement\r\ntest announcement\r\ntest announcement\r\ntest announcement\r\ntest announcement\r\ntest announcement ', `announcement_date` = '2015-01-05' WHERE `announcement_id` = 101 
Filename: C:\wamp\www\nid\system\database\DB_driver.php 
Line Number: 330
```

Comment: please put your query

Comment: UPDATE `announcement_detail` SET `announcement_title` = 'test1', `announcement_desc` = 'test announcement\r\ntest announcement\r\ntest announcement\r\ntest announcement\r\ntest announcement\r\ntest announcement ', `announcement_date` = '2015-01-05' WHERE `announcement_id` = '101'

Comment: See the error's screenshot:https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqqbvvx08xfwy76/test.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this active record:

```
$data = array(
         "announcement_title" => "test1",
         "announcement_desc"  => "some description",
         "announcement_date"  => "2015-01-05"

);

$this->db->update("announcement_detail",$data);
$this->db->where("announcement_id",101);
```

Comment: It reflects the db but it does not return any thing and this also works

Comment: please put it at the end of query and give me the result: echo $this->db->last_query();exit;

Comment: Give a screen shot from the last_query() output please

Answer (score 0):

Are you escaping your '\' ? See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-literals.html

Comment: my query works properly in localhost but when run my project its give me error.